# What is a gas lane in chainlink and blockchain?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink, brownie, evm

I do understand the concept of gas in the ethereum blockchain and why gas is needed to compensate miners for providing computing power to the network. However, when I was reading up on the chainlink vrf get a random number documentation it says that the keyhash tells you the gas lane to use. It would be really helpful if someone could further explain what a gas lane in blockchain is.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

So we know that Eth gas is always subject to change and with chainlink vrf there will be random values with your request, so you need to set a limit to how much to spend on each request. The reason chainlink uses a Gas lane is because the lanes are important for setting the ceiling limit of each request... think of it as your entry into the bet.